# Changing mouse cursor in C# UWP project on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, wpf, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to change my mouse cursor to 'waiting' in my View (MainPage.xaml) while an operation in the viewmodel is running.
This is a Universal Windows Project

I have found this:
[Change cursor in Windows Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472202/change-cursor-in-windows-store-apps)

Based on this solution I have created a property 'cursor' of Windows.UI.Core.Cursortype in my ViewModel:

```
cursor = CoreCursorType.Wait;
```

In the View this is being processed:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(mv.cursor, 0);
```

When the code is being used in the constructor of page, the updated cursor is visible. However when I handle the 'PropertyChanged' event, it is not.

The code has no errors, has been processed, and the Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor is updated.
However, this change is not visible on screen.

I have also tried these other options:

[Changing the cursor in WPF sometimes works, sometimes doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307004/changing-the-cursor-in-wpf-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt)
[display Hourglass when application is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480966/display-hourglass-when-application-is-busy)

These options do not work because:

- I am using a page, it does not have a Cursor property
- There is no Mouse object

How can I update the cursor? A binding to the viewmodel would be my preferred solution.

Update: Upon further investigation. The cursor **is changed** when I am viewing my application on my developing machine. (x64)
It **is not changed** when I am viewing my application on my Raspberry Pi (ARM).

Update: I have found a solution for binding the cursor by a dependency property:
[Setting a custom property within a WPF/Silverlight page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657778/setting-a-custom-property-within-a-wpf-silverlight-page)

Comment: Where exactly you have to bind it to?

Comment: Why you have to handle PropertyChanged in this case?Update the cursor when viewmodell operation is going on

Comment: @LovetoCode. How can I update the cursor. I feel I have the code but I do not see the selected cursor.

Comment: You are changing windows cursor using Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(mv.cursor, 0);. Not modifying UI at all.

Comment: @LoveToCode. I am updating the cursor in the ViewModel, but I do not see the updated cursor.

Comment: May be its blocking UI. Use async operation. If you post the code would be helpful

Comment: After further investigating I have found a difference. The problem with the mousepointer only exists on my Raspberry Pi.