# XAML Inheritance (not code-behind)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, inheritance

How is **inheritance** accomplished in *XAML*?

Is it true that only the code-behind can be inherited and not the *.xaml* ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271407/640378))? Is including the parent in the child control's **namespace** the only way of doing it?

There seems to be no general "inheritance" per se in *XAML*. There are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225878/640378) about inheriting `UserControl`, etc. but not **general inheritance**.

**Problem:**

I have 2 xaml files, `File1.xaml` and `File2.xaml`, which are very alike. Can I create a `SuperFile.xaml` and put the bulk of the following code in it?

```
<UserControl ... >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions ... />

        <DockPanel ... >
            <ToolBar ... >
                <!-- Some Buttons here:
                     File1.xaml to contain the Buttons "View" and "Export"
                     File2.xaml to contain the Buttons "Edit" and "Delete"
                 -->
            </ToolBar>
        </DockPanel>

        <igDP:XamDataGrid MouseDoubleClick="xamDataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick" ... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The only things that **differ** in `File1.xaml` and `File2.xaml` are:

1. `Button`s in the `ToolBar` (see comment in the code)
2. The *properties* of `XamDataGrid`, primarily the events (what they do in each case).

How can I achieve this? Would I have to write the code-behind files for both the children **separately**?

Comment: Do you truly need inheritance, or simply reuse the same class and have a flag that signals which mode you're in?

Comment: @JoelLucsy I could do that if it was only the "eventing" that differed for both the files. How would I be able to have different `Button`s if I used the same _xaml_? Can a **flag** be used even in a _xaml_?

Comment: Sure, bind the button's Visibility property to the button. You'd have to use a converter to change from bool to the Visibility enum, but there are plenty of examples of that out there.

Comment: @JoelLucsy I guess your suggestion would have worked in this case, but I'm going by the `ResourceDictionary` way because it'll help me understand how to use it (at least for a future use-case). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx)

Put all your generic templates and styles in a `ResourceDictionary`, then have both your `UserControls` import that `ResourceDictionary`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseStylesAndTemplates.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! By following this approach, will I be able to embed different sets of `Button`s in the 2 child _XAMLs_? For instance, `File1.xaml` should have the `Button`s "View" and "Export" within the `ToolBar` and `File2.xaml` should have the `Button`s "Edit" and "Delete". See the edit in the question.

Comment: @maelstrom3 I don't see why you wouldn't be able to. Your base styles will all be pulled from the `ResourceDictionary`, while your individual components such as the buttons will be defined in your individual `UserControls`

Comment: I'm not so experienced in _WPF_ and hence haven't used _Styles_ yet. So, I'll take your word for it :) and try it out.

Comment: I got the thing partially working. I have a `DataTemplate` in *SuperFile.xaml* which I'm applying to a `ContentControl` in *File1.xaml*. But, how can add `Button`s to the `DataTemplate`-generated element `ToolBar`? See the code-snippet in the question for how *SuperFile.xaml* looks like.