# How to use Setters inside the same Style to change differently elements of the same type inside the styled Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` and in it two `Path`s. When one style is applied on the `Grid`, the first `Path` should have some `Data`, and the second some other data. When the seconds style is applied, the first `Path` should have another `Data`, and the second `Path` should have another different `Data`. I wish to be able to set the `Setter`'s target element name.

I tried the code below. I get two crosses instead of one triangle in the left and one cross in the right.

```
<Window x:Class="cs_wpf_test_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="styleWithPlusSign" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 5,95 L 95,95 50,5 5,95"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 50,10 L 50,10 L 50,90 M 10,50 L 90,50"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Path Stroke="Blue"
                Stretch="Fill"
                x:Name="MyFirstPath"
              Style="{StaticResource styleWithPlusSign}"
              />
        <Path Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="4"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                x:Name="MySecondPath"
              Style="{StaticResource styleWithPlusSign}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: actual result]

I get the wished result using this inflexible code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Stroke="Blue"
        Stretch="Fill"
        x:Name="MyFirstPath"
        Data="M 5,95 L 95,95 50,5 5,95"
        />
    <Path Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="4"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        x:Name="MySecondPath"
        Data="M 50,10 L 50,10 L 50,90 M 10,50 L 90,50"/>
</Grid>
```

Screenshot:

[image: wished result]

If I try to use `TargetName` attribute of the `Setter`s I get errors:

> XDG0029 | The name "MyFirstPath" is not recognized.
>
> XDG0029 | The name "MySecondPath" is not recognized.

## Update

I am sorry for the unclarity. I want 2 styles, e.g. `styleWithPlusSign` and `styleWithMinusSign`.

- The `styleWithPlusSign` should set a triangle with a corner oriented up and a cross in the right.
- The `styleWithMinusSign` should set a triangle with a corner oriented down and a minus sign (a line) in the right.

Comment: Make two styles instead of one... one style for each path

Comment: why do you speak about another style, you have defined only one style:styleWithPlusSign? or i missunderstant what you want to do

Comment: @Frenchy In my actual application I want to use 2 styles (the `styleWithPlusSign` and another one `styleWithMinusSign`), instead of 4.

Comment: you want to draw a triangle in column 0 and cross in column 1 with the same style?

Comment: I guess what he actually wants is two styles, one for each path. And both styles with some triggers which changes the path data. @silviubogan, please edit your question with what you exactly want. as it is, its not really clear

Comment: @Frenchy I updated my question.

Comment: @Frenchy All the code is [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55469146/258462). Thank you.

Comment: if your triangle is always in column zero its okay without coding, see my xaml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution with trigger: i just test if column number is 0, in this case i display a triangle, either a cross.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleWithPlusSign" TargetType="Path">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="0">
                <Setter  Property="Path.Data" Value="M 5,95 L 95,95 50,5 5,95"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 50,10 L 50,10 L 50,90 M 10,50 L 90,50"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Blue"
          Stretch="Fill"
          x:Name="MyFirstPath"
          Style="{StaticResource styleWithPlusSign}"
    />
    <Path Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black"
          StrokeThickness="4"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          x:Name="MySecondPath"
          Style="{StaticResource styleWithPlusSign}"/>
</Grid>
```

---

if you need to precise the column number for each path:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleWithPlusSign" TargetType="Path">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="0">
                <Setter  Property="Path.Data" Value="M 5,95 L 95,95 50,5 5,95"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M 50,10 L 50,10 L 50,90 M 10,50 L 90,50"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

[image]

Comment: I currently use a Binding in the MySecondPath element (`Style="{Binding ElementName=MyFirstPath, Path=Style}"` to set the style only once and achieve the same effects. Is there a more correct way?

Comment: if you have static resource its better to use it, less overhead than binding. but if you have not big amount of data in your view its not a problem.